# Check if directory contains *.ext

Tags: vb6

I working on a file system issue in vb6. I have to find out, if a given directory contains any jpg file (*.jpg).

Can anyone tell me how I can check this with vb6 functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick, simple way to check for a file's existence is to use the `Dir` command:

```
Public Function FileExists(strFileSpec As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = (Dir(strFileSpec) <> "")
End Function
```

This works okay with wildcards, so you could:

```
If Not FileExists("C:\MyFolder\*.JPG") Then
    MsgBox "No JPegs found in C:\MyFolder")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

'Check to see if the drive\file exists, Open it.
'True = OK, False = Error

```
Private Function ckFile() As Boolean    

On Error GoTo Err_XXX


Dim SelectedJPGFile as String
Dim gPath as String 'Specify your given directory
  Dim sTemp As String
  Dim sDrive As String
  Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
  Dim fil As File
  Dim ts As TextStream
  Dim sStream As String

     If SelectedJPGFile = "" Then
       sTemp = sDrive & ":\*.jpg"

     Else
       sTemp = gPath & "\" & SelectedJPGFile 
     End If


On Error GoTo Err_First
    Set fil = fso.GetFile(sTemp)
On Error GoTo Err_XXX
    sFullName = sTemp
    Set ts = fil.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
    ckFile = True
    GoTo Exit_XXX


Exit_XXX:
    SelectedJPGFile  = ""
    Exit Function
    If Err.Number = 53 Then
        ckFile = False


      MsgBox "Drive does not contain the JPG File
." & vbCrLf & _
                    "Please check the File and try again.", vbCritical, "Check Directory"
        Resume Exit_XXX
    End If
Err_First:

Err_XXX:
    ckFile = False
    MsgBox Err.DESCRIPTION
    Resume Exit_XXX
End Function
```